# Flutter: Path Provider In Background

Tags: android, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use path provider in `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler)`, it always gives me

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel
> plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  try {
    final Directory appDocumentsDirector =
        await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.test_path_provider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this.getFlutterEngine());
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
package com.example.test_path_provider;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    PathProviderPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin"));
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test_path_provider">
   <application
        android:label="test_path_provider"
        android:name=".Application"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**flutter doctor -v**

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.18362.30], locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 2.10.5 at C:\src\flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (3 weeks ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
> • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
> • Dart version 2.16.2
> • DevTools version 2.9.2
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 31.0.0)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>
> [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019
> 16.11.7)
> • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
> • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.31911.196
> • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
> https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
>
> [√] VS Code
> • VS Code at C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.29.0
>
> [√] Connected device (3 available)
> • SM A205F (mobile) • R58M361JGKH • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
> • Windows (desktop) • windows     • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.30]
> • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 101.0.4951.64
>
> [√] HTTP Host Availability
> • All required HTTP hosts are available
>
> • No issues found!

**already tried**

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```